# any down side if i return from function in try block

Tags: python, exception

I am working on some python function and it worked well the way i implemented but i am looking for suggestion in terms of better coding practice and of course if my current implementation has issue.

Below is the code snippet for context of issue:

```
def foo():
    try:
       [doing some file operations]
       ....
       return <intended variable>
    except:
       [logging, non recoverable exception]
       sys.exit(1)
```

Wondering if keeping my return statement in try block is bad coding practice.

Comment: Imo it's  cleaner if the return is at the bottom of the function in this case. There really isn't a right answer.

Comment: It depends on what is in the `except` block. If you _always_ return the variable, whether from the `try` or `except` you ought to return it once in a `finally` or simply at the end of the function. If not, I don’t see the problem. You could always put the return in an `else` clause if the line that returns the variable definitely won’t raise an exception. As long as it’s clear, I think it’s just down to preference.

Comment: Returning in a try block seems ok to me. Although, I would be pretty surprised by a function catching an exception an exiting instead of letting me handle the error, I think that's the bad practice in there.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon exception happening before return statement, so function would not return and control will follow to except block.

Comment: @BlackFurry Just let the error bubble up. You are exiting and hiding the exception. If the program is to exit with code 1, let it crash and print its valuable traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use try/except without else nor finally part, I'd say this is a clear code (you don't have to think whether else or finally execute or not as it may vary by language)...

However, you should keep your try blocks as short as you can and specify as detailed exceptions as you can - never use bare exception, it will catch literally all exceptions, including keyboard interruption... although you're exiting anyway.

So if you're not using any strange things, this try/except/else is better:

```
try:
    risky_operation_that_might_break_something()
except Exception: #better practice, still a bit too wide
    #logging here
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    #non-risky rest of the code
    return something
```